# get_attached_media() on author page not working

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, attachments, author

I have a very annoying and simple problem.

I can use [get_attached_media()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media) on a taxonomy page to get the attached media of a custom post.

```
function author_loop() {

    $post = get_the_ID();

    // Where the problem lies, only on author pages. get_attached_media returns nothing.
    $attach = get_attached_media( 'application/pdf', $post );
    $attach = current( $attach );

    $attach_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attach );

    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $attach_url, get_the_title() );

}
```

But when I use the exact same function on the author page, I get returned an empty array.

I've spent so long trying to figure out why but no luck.

Everything in the loop for both the taxonomy and author pages behaves fine except finding the attached media for post.

Please help.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have for your author page?

Comment: Please file an [edit] and show your author archive loop and the filename of the template where you run this loop.

Comment: The theme uses the Genesis Framework with a hook which runs through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a simple misunderstanding of what this function actually does and what it should be used for: [`get_attached_media()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_media/) simply fetches all *child* posts for a given posts:

```
if ( ! $post = get_post( $post ) )
    return array();

$args = array(
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => $type,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
);
```

From [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media):

> Retrieve media attached to the passed post. Uses `get_children()`.

If you are using this on an author archive, the main query will be retrievable by using [`$GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_queried_object()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) or just `get_queried_object()`. Again from the *Codex* page:

> If you're on an author archive, it will return the author object

Now, an author per default is a `WP_User` and not a `post` object that can have children. To retrieve all media that an author attached to posts, you will have to loop through the posts of an author and then query for the media *inside* the loop by using `$media = get_attached_media( get_the_ID() );`.